# Spring Boot @ExceptionHandler hide Exception Name

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot 1.3.X and have the following:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/foo")
public class FooController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, params = { "fooBar" })
    public Collection<Entry> firstFoo() {
        //Do something
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, params = { "anotherFooBar" })
    public Collection<Entry> secondFoo() {
        //Do something other
    }

}
```

Which works as expected. When passing a wrong param, the following exception is raised:

```
{
    "error": "Bad Request", 
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.bind.UnsatisfiedServletRequestParameterException", 
    "message": "Parameter conditions \"fooBar\" OR \"anotherFooBar\" not met for actual request parameters: elementalFormulae={C11}", 
    "path": "/foo", 
    "status": 400, 
    "timestamp": 1455287433961
}
```

I then created an `ExceptionHandler` as seen below:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExcptionController {

    @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, reason="Invalid parameter")
    @ExceptionHandler(UnsatisfiedServletRequestParameterException.class)
    private void foo() {
        //Log exception
    }
}
```

Which raises the following Exception:

```
{
    "error": "Bad Request", 
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.bind.UnsatisfiedServletRequestParameterException", 
    "message": "Invalid parameter", 
    "path": "/api/foo", 
    "status": 400, 
    "timestamp": 1455287904886
}
```

Is it possible to exclude the *exception* field from the `JSON` representation?

Comment: Would @JSONIgnore do the trick?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the *Error Attributes* in your controller advice and then, only keep the *Exposable Fields*. Something like following:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExcptionController {
    private static final List<String> EXPOSABLE_FIELDS = asList("timestamp", "status", "error", "message", "path");

    @Autowired private ErrorAttributes errorAttributes;

    @ExceptionHandler(UnsatisfiedServletRequestParameterException.class)
    private ResponseEntity foo(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Map<String, Object> errors = getErrorAttributes(request);
        errors.put("message", "Invalid parameter");

        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(errors);
    }

    private Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(HttpServletRequest request) {
        ServletRequestAttributes requestAttributes = new ServletRequestAttributes(request);
        final boolean WITHOUT_STACK_TRACE = false;
        Map<String, Object> attributes = errorAttributes.getErrorAttributes(requestAttributes, WITHOUT_STACK_TRACE);

        // log exception before removing it
        attributes.keySet().removeIf(key -> !EXPOSABLE_FIELDS.contains(key));

        return attributes;
    }
}
```

Comment: This kind of works, meaning the fields not listed inside EXPOSABLE_FIELDS, are removed from the error attributes, but the returned JSON still looks as above

Comment: `exception` field is still there?

Comment: Yes, it is still shown, although errors does not contain the field anymore.

Comment: I will give it a try in the next few hours, and reply back to you

Answer (score 6):

For those who use spring boot 2.x.
Since version 2.0.0 default implemetation of ErrorAttrubutes is [DefaultErrorAttributes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/error/DefaultErrorAttributes.html).
When possible DefaultErrorAttributes provides  exception stack trace. Deleting this field from the response is possible by setting:

```
server.error.include-stacktrace: never
```

Comment: Yep, this work with Spring Boot 2.1.x and probably with spring 1.x, can you tell us where is the doc about this parameter ? Also from what I can find, "never" is supposed to be the default value, but it's clearly not.

Comment: Very late answer, but I hope it will be useful. Link to [error properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorProperties.IncludeStacktrace.html)

Answer (score 5):

I have solved this bean-style. Adding the following bean definition to REST layer configuration replacing `ErrorAttributes` used solved issue in my case without any runtime code on exception processing.

```
@Bean
public ErrorAttributes errorAttributes() {
    return new DefaultErrorAttributes() {

        @Override
        public Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(
                RequestAttributes requestAttributes,
                boolean includeStackTrace) {

            Map<String, Object> errorAttributes
                = super.getErrorAttributes(requestAttributes, includeStackTrace);
            errorAttributes.remove("exception");
            return errorAttributes;
        }

    };
}
```

Comment: simple and best solution

Comment: Instead, a simple property in application.properties would do the trick: - server.error.include-exception=false

Comment: If you do not want to configure anything else and you are OK to have appropriate configuration in all deployments - seems like really better option. But I personally dislike properties configuration for such a fundamental thing.