# Java Spring - Handle exception thrown when @RequestBody is null

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a rest api in `Java Spring Boot`. I am making a `POST` request to `api`. If there is a data in the body it works fine but when no data is passed, it gives a `400 Bad Request` response:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-05-03T13:32:36.746+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Required request body is missing: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.package.MyResponse> com.package.MyController.getData(com.package.MyRequest)",
    "path": "/api/"
}
```

How can I hide the `package information` and `class name` from the message in response? It should return mesage as:

```
"message": "Required request body is missing."
```

One option is to set `@RequestBody(required=false)` and then handle manually inside, but I want to avoid.

It would be great if someone can help. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot @ExceptionHandler hide Exception Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35365266/spring-boot-exceptionhandler-hide-exception-name) The solution is analogous for message vs exception-name. Since message is a free text, you will either need to leave it out completely or do some manual filtering.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `RestControllerAdvice` extend it with `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`. In implementation override corresponding method and send your custom message. In your case method will be `handleHttpMessageNotReadable` from `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`.

Here is the sample code:

```
/**
 * Intercept exception to response with error
 */
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ApplicationExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex, HttpHeaders headers,
      HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    // your custom implementation
  }
}
```